# How To Get Value Of SelectedItem In List

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to get the value of a selectedItem in A listView,this is my code.

```
public class BlogClass{

     public string NewId;
     public BlogClass()
     {
      additem();
     }


    public class BlogViews
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayTopic { get; set; }
        public string DisplayMain { get; set; }
        public ImageSource BlogImageSource { get; set; }
    }

    public List<BlogViews> BlogList1 = new List<BlogViews>();

    public void additem()
    {
        BlogList1.Add(new BlogViews { id = "1", DisplayMain = "Margret", DisplayTopic = "Mensah" });
        BlogList1.Add(new BlogViews { id = "2", DisplayMain = "Maet", DisplayTopic = "Meah" });
        BlogList1.Add(new BlogViews { id = "3", DisplayMain = "dargret", DisplayTopic = "sah" });
        BlogList1.Add(new BlogViews { id = "4", DisplayMain = "gret", DisplayTopic = "Meh" });

        BlogListView.ItemsSource = BlogList1;
    }
```

}

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="demoListView.ImageCellPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView  x:Name="BloglistView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding   BlogImageSource}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding id}"
                                TextColor="#f35e20" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding DisplayTopic}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                               <Label Text="{Binding DisplayMain}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Question**

Now When i select an item on BlogListView I want to set the Value of NewId to that of id according to the selecteditem.Hence gatting the value of id

Comment: What did you find when you looked at bloglist1? there are some obvious properties that should have attracted attention. What specifically then are you struggling with

Comment: @BugFinder please,i dont understand

Comment: @BugFinder, I have a custom made ListView in my xaml code called BlogListView and in each cell there a three string Bound to strings id,DisplayMain,DisplayTopic which are in BlogView Class, hence i want to get the id value when i select an item according to the selecteditem,i hope this answers he question.

Comment: Where is your xaml lisview, please update that also

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi i added the xaml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `ItemTapped` event for the listview:

**XAML:**

```
<ListView  x:Name="BloglistView" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding   BlogImageSource}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding id}"
                                TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayTopic}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayMain}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
   var selectedItem = e.Item as BlogViews;   
   NewId = selectedItem.id;
}
```